# Is a wave (front) able to represent (the topology) of a surface?

Tags: optics

Imagine light is being shed onto a surface and reflected. Depending on the surface, the light will be emitted in many ways, probably mostly diffuse.

Question 1: Will all the reflected photons form a wave (front)?

Question 2: Will this "reflected wave" represent the topology of the surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and indeed this is the basis of [Tolansky interferometry](https://www.nature.com/articles/152722a0), which occupied a fair bit of my time as a PhD student. No doubt there are other related techniques that I haven't encountered.

When light reflects from a surface each point on that surface behaves as a point emitter and the reflected wave can be constructed using the [Huygens construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle). The differing heights of the emitters on a rough surface change their relative phases so the interference pattern you get is dependent on the topology of the surface.

Actually using this requires considerable care. You normally need a carefully constructed light source and the amount of information that can be recovered is limited. Nevertheless it is sometimes a very useful way to examine surfaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do I take into account diffusive reflections and the like?

Comment: According to https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Tolansky-Verfahren (only available in German), it is used to determine the depth of a layer, not to determine the topology of its surface(?).

Comment: @Ben It does measure the thickness of a layer, but you make that layer by putting a plate above the surface so the layer is the air gap between the plate and the surface. The surface topology changes the thickness of the air gap, so by measuring the thickness of the layer you are measuring the surface topology.

Comment: I used it for measuring the topology of thin metal films deposited on a substrate.

Comment: ah, ok, I understand. But then it is probably also subject to the topology of that plate above the surface?

Comment: @Ben yes, but it's routine to get optically flat plates that are smooth down to the nanometre scale.